# Solving for left eigenvector of $4\times4$ stochastic row matrix

Tags: probability, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Attempting to solve the matrix equation for left eigenvector $[w~x~y~z]$ given the following stochastic matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \frac12 & \frac12 & 0\\
\frac13 & 0 & \frac13 & \frac13\\
\frac12 & 0 & 0 & \frac12\\
0 & \frac12 & \frac12 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

This a practice problem from an online course I'm taking. The idea is to demonstrate by hand that you get the same steady state distribution vector by solving for the eigenvector whose eigenvalue is one as you do by iterating the matrix $50$ or $100$ times.  The answer given is $\left[\frac3{13}~\frac3{13}~\frac4{13}~\frac3{13}\right]$.  I get close by using Gaussian elimination but can't quite get it done.

Comment: What do you mean by "I get close by using Gaussian elimination"? What answer did you get and how?

Comment: I meant that I was able to row reduce down to y=(4/3)z, which is correct, but could not get the correct answers for w and x.  Actually, I regret posting this question - a fellow student suggested solving the determinate (A^T-1) where A is the matrix above row steady state vector will be the column steady state vector of A^T.  I took her advice and solved it this morning with 4 row reductions.  Answer was w=z, x=z, y=(4/3)z, z=z. Putting in column form and normalizing you get [(3/13)  (3/13)  4 3]

Comment: Solving for row vector, got y=(4/3) z which is correct.  Could not get the rest of the variables.  Tried alternate approach this morning of solving det (A^T-1) for column eigenvector.  Worked - sorry I posted this question - should have explored alternative approaches first.  Thx.

Comment: miss hit the enter key in first comment: should read "Putting in column form and normalizing you get [(3/13) (3/13) (4/13) (3/13)]"

Comment: Row-reducing $A^T - I$ is the standard approach. In any case, glad you figured it out

Comment: Thank you very much!!